# Projeto Laravel funciona em um local e não funciona em outro

Tags: laravel, login, collection, iis

Boa noite, eu estou com um projeto sendo feito no laravel 5.8 e estou com um certo problema, em resumo o projeto funciona no meu trabalho, mas não funciona em casa.

A questão é o seguinte, o projeto abre e executa normalmente no local onde eu trabalho, que é onde fiz ele todo. Eu criei um repositório .git e clonei o projeto para trabalhar em casa, copiei o .env e coloquei em casa, usei composer e npm install, tudo certinho, instalei a mesma versão do php e IIS Express e gerei o banco mysql. O projeto até roda em casa, exibe a maioria das telas. Mas estou basicamente com 2 problemas:

1- O login (feito com o make:auth) não é realizado, mesmo com as informações inseridas corretamente, quando clica em logar ele retorna para a mesma tela sem efetuar o login. Por outro lado, ao registrar, o registro é feito corretamente e redireciona com o usuário logado. Se eu der logout com esse usuário, não consigo mais logar (volta ao problema inicial).

2- Eu criei uma tela de perfil para o usuário, entretanto, ao acessa-la está retornando erro com a seguinte mensagem: "Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::user does not exist".

O erro ocorre na seguinte função do meu ProfileController:

```
    public function show($username){

    $user_id = User::select('id')->where('username', $username)->first();
    $profile = User::find($user_id)->user();

    return view('perfil/perfil', ['profile'=>$profile]);
}
```

Especificamente na linha `$profile = User::find ($user_id)->user();`.

Profile Model:

```
   class Profile extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id','main_sheet', 'main_camp', 'age', 'location', 'avatar'
    ];

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

User Model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'username'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function profile(){
        return $this->hasMany(Profile::class);
    }

}
```

Enfim, estes são os problemas que estou tendo. Lembrando que o projeto funciona perfeitamente no meu local de trabalho. Tanto o login como a tela de perfil, já tentei várias coisas, mas nada resolveu.

Muito obrigado para quem puder ajudar.

Comment: O `Model User` não tem a relação `user` tem a relação `profile()`: linha do problema: `$profile = User::find($user_id)->user();`, deveria ser `$profile = User::find($user_id)->profile();` O seu problema não é que o Laravel executa no trabalho e não executa em casa o seu problema é programação errada mesmo utilizando coisas que não existem no `model` ...

Comment: Outro problema a linha `$user_id = User::select('id')->where('username', $username)->first();` retornar um dado assim `$user_id->id` e na próxima linha deveria ser `$profile = User::find($user_id->id)->profile();`, resumindo o problema realmente é na programação. Observação se as linhas derem certo é assim se não tem que verificar se retornou realmente alguma coisa

Comment: Bom dia. De fato as observações que voce fez são pertinentes, ao alterar o que falou a tela de perfil funcionou, entretanto, a programação está idêntica ao do meu trabalho e lá funciona, isso que eu acho estranho. Outra coisa é que a tela de login continua sem funcionar, sendo que lá funciona perfeitamente. Muito obrigado pela atenção

Comment: Sinceridade eu duvido que os códigos são os mesmos, afinal agora deu certo com as minhas correções.

Comment: Eu só posso demonstrar isso na segunda feira tirando prints, mas sim, são iguais, inclusive eu reupei ontem para o github e comparei tudo para ter certeza de que estava igual. O que pode ser é que talvez eu alterei coisas no trabalho para teste e não me lembro, mas não creio. De qualquer forma, o login eu tenho certeza de que não houve alteração e os arquivos estão idênticos. Aproveitando, como que eu puxo as informações do controller para a tela após essas alterações? Antes estava {{$profile->avatar}}, agora ta dando undefined, pois o avatar nao tem na tabela User, apenas na Profile. Obrigado

Comment: Rapaz duvido novamente, olha só a sua nova duvida... Deixa eu ver o seu github? porque se o avatar esta em profile naquela linha está retornando profile é só utilizar se o dado estiver presente ... Veja como código se comportam diferente se um esta errado.

Comment: Posso sim https://github.com/guipolitano/studies/tree/master/dnd

Comment: é nada mais errado do que está lá! o relacionamento está errado ... vixe... bastante coisas estão erradas

Comment: Hauahuh, sou bem iniciante ainda. Esse projeto é justamente para aprender, naturalmente que terá muitos erros =P O que me estranha é não funcionar em casa e funcionar no trabalho =/

Comment: Entãooooooooo algo de estranho deve ser codigo Harry Potter ... é mágico kkk